# How big can a money tree grow

Tags: houseplants

[image]

We have a money tree little one then I starter repotting it every time I feel it needs to grow because its roots looks muscular.

I moved it to a half drum container now and I notice it is getting bigger.

How big can it grow?

Answer (score 1):

In the ground in its natural habitat, Pachira aquatica can get up to 20 metres, but average height and spread in a pot as a houseplant, probably up to 150cm (up to five feet) in a large pot. The advice on repotting is to do it about every 3 years, and only when it's got too large for its pot. https://www.plantopedia.com/pachira-aquatica/